# Problems running bitbake on Kirkstone

Tags: yocto, bitbake

So I was able to set up Poky Honister and get that working a while back but I'd like to move to Kirkstone for a variety of reasons.

I keep getting the following errors and I have no idea whats going on I've spent the last 8 hours trying to get past these errors to no avail.

Any ideas?

I have read the following url

https://low-level.wiki/yocto/kirkstone-upgrade.html

This problem doesn't seem to be on that site so I'm very confused.

I'm going to try and pull down the entire project again just in case I maybe pulled down an incorrect branch somewhere

```
WARNING: pseudo-native-1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.yoctoproject.org/pseudo;branch=oe-core, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: gnu-config-native-20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git;protocol=https;branch=master, attempting MIRRORS if available
WARNING: pkgconfig-native-0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pkg-config/pkg-config.git;branch=master;protocol=https, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: binutils-cross-aarch64-2.38-r0 do_unpack: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1871"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts/cross-intercept:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/crossscripts:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/bitbake/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/justin"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat remote set-url origin git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git failed with exit code 1, output:\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools/git", line 26, in <module>\n    os.execv(real_git, sys.argv)\nTypeError: execv: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType\n', None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-aarch64/2.38-r0/temp/log.do_unpack.4409
ERROR: Task (/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.38.bb:do_unpack) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: gnu-config-native-20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1871"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts/native-intercept:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/bitbake/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/justin"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat remote failed with exit code 1, output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools/git", line 26, in <module>
    os.execv(real_git, sys.argv)
TypeError: execv: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType

ERROR: gnu-config-native-20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/config.git;protocol=https;branch=master')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gnu-config-native/20211108+gitAUTOINC+191bcb948f-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.4406
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: pkgconfig-native-0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1871"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts/native-intercept:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/bitbake/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/justin"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat remote failed with exit code 1, output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools/git", line 26, in <module>
    os.execv(real_git, sys.argv)
TypeError: execv: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType

ERROR: pkgconfig-native-0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pkg-config/pkg-config.git;branch=master;protocol=https')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pkgconfig-native/0.29.2+gitAUTOINC+d97db4fae4-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.4407
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: pseudo-native-1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1871"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts/native-intercept:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/scripts:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/bitbake/bin:/home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/justin"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat clone --bare --mirror git://git.yoctoproject.org/pseudo /home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/downloads/git2/git.yoctoproject.org.pseudo --progress failed with exit code 1, no output
ERROR: pseudo-native-1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://git.yoctoproject.org/pseudo;branch=oe-core')
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/justin/kirkstone-build/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/pseudo-native/1.9.0+gitAUTOINC+2b4b88eb51-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.4408
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 74 tasks of which 70 didn't need to be rerun and 4 failed.

Summary: 4 tasks failed:
  /home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.38.bb:do_unpack
  virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_fetch
  virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_fetch
  virtual:native:/home/justin/poky-kirkstone/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_fetch
Summary: There were 55 WARNING messages.
Summary: There were 7 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Did you just do a `cleansstate` or really remove the whole build folder after migrating? Did you also remove the `sources` and maybe even the `downloads` to make sure no old stuff survived?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the cause of this issue was but I went back through and used the exact same layer/config files that I use previously and simply pulled down all the layers I used fresh making sure that the branch was set to kirkstone.

This time around when I went to run bitbake it worked perfectly and is currently running.

So if you see these errors just try to start over like I did. I'm guessing that at some point I probably pulled down an outdated branch.

If the bitbake process fails again I will post a follow up but for now I'm pretty optimistic it will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this such as I did: I experienced the same error message for a different Yocto build. In my case deleting the `build/tmp` folder fixed it.

I noticed that the `myYoctoDir1/build/tmp/hosttools/git` script that throws the error was a symbolic link pointing to a different Yocto base directory (i.e. `myYoctoDir2/layers/poky/scripts/git`) - so I assume I sourced the Yocto environment in the other directory (`myYoctoDir2`) before starting my first build in this directory (`myYoctoDir1`), which creates the `tmp` folder.